# Will this kind of app be accepted?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an app for a company. The company aims at introducing models from foreign to domestic and the company wants to display all the models it owns on ipad so that some other companys who may be interested in can browse these models.

But when I read the "[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)", I am not sure whether this kind of app could be accepted:

2.12 Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected.

I am afraid that this kind of app which is not for entertainment nor for normal customer will not be accepted. Can someone can give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app if for a legit model agency I don't think there would be any problems being accepted to the AppStore.

To me however every red flag in the book is up given your short description here - I expect that the Apple reviewers will have the same knee-jerk reaction to what sound like a dicey operation.

You could make an HTML 5 based web-app instead targeted at iPhone and iPad. Working with an web-app you don't have to deal with the Apple review process.

Make sure that your client doesn't inadvertantly drag you in to any legal grey areas.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb if you're making an application over a web app for iOS bets are that you aren't literally just adding the website wrapped up into the app. The guideline interpreted by me means that you should beware making an iOS app for something a web app or an iOS ready site would've sufficed doing. When you say you'd let companies browse through products it makes it sound like the user will have the ability to interact with products in an iOS native way which is why us developers make apps. I'm not sure where Apple was going with the entertainment value part though but I'm sure that doesn't apply to business apps anyways.